# Human Bones classification and anatomy quiz

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy

I'm a junior Biology Student and I came across this Human Anatomy Question:

In respect to the bone characteristics, mark the correct answer:

A) Even bones: Palatine, Inferior jaw, Parietal.

B) Examples of Long Bones: Sternum and Radius-clavicle.

C) Some Mixed Bones are (I couldn't find a better translation for "ossos mistos" in portuguese): vertebrae, ribs, hip bones.

D)Plane Bones protect organs and form cavities, for instance we have: Ribs and Sternum.

E)Odd and Plane Bones: Occipital, Frontal and Sternum.

I am almost sure that options A through C are incorrect. I'm between options D and E, but in option E I am really sure only that the Sternum Bone is correct. I couldn't find a reliable source that said explicitly that the Occipital and Frontal Bone are Plane and Odd.
And I think option D has a flaw mainly because the Sternum Bone does not form any cavities.

Comment: As you not in your question, I think there are some difficulties in translation. I suspect that "plane" should be translated as "flat", that "mixed" is likely "irregular", and "odd" and "even" are "paired" and "unpaired". Does that sound right?

Comment: If you are voting down, please leave a comment.

Comment: Why do you think the answer C is incorrect?  %)

Comment: @kmm - here a new downvote. I am downvoting because this is a schoolbook example of a  set of dry, contentless textbook-answerable questions not quite interesting for this community at large. I can't vote for closure as it is on topic. So, a downvote it is.

Comment: @AliceD I disagree. Here's a question with a valid attempt at answer, seeking clarification. Seems like a reasonable homework question. Maybe not the more interesting, but valid and worthy of answering.

Comment: @kmm - it's a downvote, nothing more. I voted to leave open. I support this question, I just don't think it rocks because it is so textbooky.

Comment: It would be good if you posted the original text in Portuguese so someone fluent in both languages can translate it better, as is the translation issues are preventing the question from being answered.

Comment: @Jessica Veloso (if you ever return to SE), did you ever get the answer to see if our attempts at translating were correct?? :p

Answer (score 3):

@KMM's comment above appears to be on the right rack.

```
"plane" = "flat"
"mixed" = "irregular"
"even" & "odd" = "paired" & "unpaired"
```

That being said:

- A = FALSE because jaw bones are not paired
- B = FALSE because sternum is not a long bone (it's a flat bone)
- C = FALSE because ribs are not *irregular* bones (they're flat bones)
- D = TRUE because both are flat bones and protect organs
- E = FALSE but ONLY under the assumption of the persistence of a metopic suture (frontal suture) causing the frontal bone to be split (and therefore "paired").

Answer (score 0):

If I had 90 seconds to answer this question I'd mark answer "**C**".

Vertebrae & Ribs & Hip bones all are mixed bones.